# How get a return from post method with HttpRepsonse

Tags: angular, httpresponse

I can't get the result for headers.get(status) from the return message.

I found that maybe it's because my http.post don't have the Httpresponse so angular can't get the headers information.

service.ts:

```
onCreateData(service: LoginFormService) {

const request = JSON.stringify(
  { dataYear: service.form.get('dataYear').value,
    dataMonth: service.form.get('dataMonth').value,
    population: service.form.get('population').value,
    sources: service.form.get('sources').value
  }
);

return this.http.post(this.createDataUrl, request, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError('onCreateData'))
  );
```

}

component.ts:

```
onSubmit() {
this.service.onCreateData(this.service).subscribe(

  (res: Response) => {
    console.log('-----');
    console.log(res.headers.get(status));
    this.service.form.reset();
    this.service.initializeFormGroup();
    this.notificationService.success(':: Submitted successfully');
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
);
```

}

If i can get the  headers.status, I would like to use it to do different notification.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please first use HttpClient instead of http because http is deprecated.

import {HttpClient, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';

Example : 1

```
 const req = new HttpRequest('POST','YOUR_URL',POST_DATA,{reportProgress: true});
return this.http.request(req);
```

Example : 2

```
this.http.post<Type of response you will get>('YOUR_URL',{
          observe: 'body',
          responseType: 'json'
        })
    }),map(
      ( response)=>{
       ///******************Do some Changes or check in Response************///
        return  response;
      }));
```

Example : 3

```
this.http.post('YOUR_URL',{
          observe: 'body',
          responseType: 'json'
        })
    }),map(
      ( response)=>{
       ///******************Do some Changes or check in Response************///
        return  response;
      }));
```